# Is it good practice to always use "use strict" in modern web apps?

Tags: javascript, web-development, web-applications

I'm learning JavaScript and just came across "use strict". It sounds like to me it should always be in play but me being a beginner I was wondering if there are scenarios/environments when we should not use "use strict" (besides super old code that doesn't support it obviously).

Comment: "Tell me a list of things (scenarios/environments)" type questions don't work on this site, with our current community, sorry, They will be closed either with one of the predefined reasons "needs more focus" or "too opinionated"- But you can try ChatGPT, it will give you a decent answer.

Comment: @DocBrown: The answer to this question is not a "list of things" and the question is therefore perfectly appropriate for this site. In short, strict mode should always be used, unless you are working on legacy unstrict code were it would be too much work or risk to make it strict.

Comment: @JacquesB: after reading it again and amon's answer, I agree. Now convince gnat, good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaScript strict mode is not enabled for legacy code for backwards compatibility reasons. But it should be used for all code that *you* write.

In practice, this happens implicitly: using JavaScript modules (import/export keywords) also activates strict mode in the current file: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#strict_mode_for_modules